# Computed Property that uses itself to compute its value?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to have a computed property that tracks that historical max of another property.  Both these attributes are a member of an ndb class.

My naive approach was the following:

```
number = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
highest_ever_number = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.highest_ever_number if self.highest_ever_number >= self.number else self.number)
```

The intent was to set the highest_ever_number to a new number if number ever surpassed highest_ever_number.

This doesn't work because highest_ever_number is initially unset.  I cannot set it to a default value using "default=0".  Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use such conditions inside a Computed Property. This whole functionality can be done within a function, so it doesn't need to be a `ComputedProperty`. A better alternative to this problem could be to create a `class method` and call it whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a computed property, you should use a normal IntegerProperty but use a _pre_put hook (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#hooks) to verify/update highest_ever_number.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but this might do the trick:

```
number = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
highest_ever_number = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.highest_ever_number if 
self.highest_ever_number and self.highest_ever_number >= self.number else self.number)
```